# Чи є різниця між словами зіставляння і зіставлення

Tags: вибір-слова, віддієслівні-іменники

Зіставл**я**ння і зіставл**е**ння, я не можу зрозуміти яке слово коли використовувати.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! У запитаннях такого роду завжди варто вказувати контекст, а також продемонструвати, які власні спроби відповісти на запитання ви зробили.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Зіставляння** описує тривалий або повторюваний процес, **зіставлення** – разовий.

Comment: Хоч без обґрунтувань, але заперечити нічого. В тлумайному словнику приклади цитат на «[зіставлення](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=36343&page=1147)» і «[зіставляння](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=137329&page=1147)», здається, лише підтверджують Вашу думку. Не знаю, чи варто їх додавати до відповіді.

Comment: Єдине що додам: «зіставлення» також використовується в (доволі рідкій, на мій погляд) прийменниковій сполуці «в зіставленні з», що є виглядає синонімічною до [не рекомендованою onlinecorrector'ом](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/як-порівняти-порівнюючи-з/) «[в порівнянні з](http://sum.in.ua/s/porivnjannja)» і позначає відповідно «якщо зіставляюти/порівнювати з». А от прийменникової сполуки «в зіставлянні з», здається, не існує — «в зіставлянні з», якщо й використовується, то в прямому значенні («в цьому зіставлянні виражається її світогляд»), а не як «зіставляючи/порівнюючи з».

Answer (score 6):

Доповню відповідь Yola.

*Зіставляння* та *зіставлення* — типовий приклад віддієслівних іменників, один з яких має значення процесу, а інший виражає наслідок цього процесу.
Тобто, зіставляння — **дія**, процес (від дієслова недок. виду), а зіставлення — **подія** (від дієслова док. виду), це те що відбулося внаслідок дії.

Аналогічно:

- *відновлювання* – *відновлення*;
- *вимірювання* – *вимірення*;
- *натискання*/*натискування* – *натиснення*;
- *переставляння* – *переставлення*.

Таке розмежування (дія-подія) використовується здебільшого для опису процесових понять.

Для зацікавлених наведу повний уривок із першоджерела:

> **8.2. Тенденція до формально-словотвірного розмежовування віддієслівних іменників зі значенням завершеного процесу (на *-ння*,
> *-ття*) і значеннями його наслідків (з різними суміжними значеннями предметності)** — з якомога послідовнішим поширенням певних випадків
> оформлення дериватів зі значенням наслідку дії за допомогою коротших
> форм, зокрема зворотної деривації (пор., наприклад, уже наявні у
> словотвірній системі української мови випадки на зразок *утворення* —
> *утвір*, *розтягнення* — *розтяг*, *випарування* — *випар*, *напруження* —
> *напруга*; сюди прилягає й розмежування термінів *словотворення* — *словотвір*), на всю систему віддієслівного словотворення (із семантичною
> спеціалізацією вже наявних слів та «куванням» нових).
>
> Найбільшого поширення в межах дії цієї тенденції набуло відмежовування від
> значень процесуальності структурно-семантичного розряду
> віддієслівних іменників на -*ка* (див. 2.6) — з прагненням до залишення
> за ними лише різних непроцесуальних значень: *обмотування* — *обмотка*
> і т. ін. У мовознавчих працях почастішало вживання термінів
> *словосполука* і *звукосполука* на місці вже усталених на сьогодні
> *словосполучення* і *звукосполучення*, оскільки сполучення має означати,
> на переконання прихильників цієї нормотворчої тенденції, тільки
> (завершений) процес.
>
> Найповнішого ж вигляду це вже набуло в різних
> проектах послідовного реформування системи українського словотворення, створюваних термінологами, наприклад: *відновлювання*, *вимірювання*, *натискання* / *натискування*, *переставляння* і под. («дія» —
> від дієслів недок. в.) — *відновлення*, *вимірення*, *натиснення*,
> *переставлення* і под. («подія» — від дієслів док. в.) — *віднова*,
> *вимір*, *натиск*, *перестановка* і под. («наслідок події») <sup>108</sup>; до рос.
> *отклонение* — *відхиляння* (тривала дія), *відхилювання* (періодично
> повторювана дія), *відхилення* (одноразова дія) і *відхил* (наслідок дії)
> <sup>109</sup>; *видовження*, *обтяження*, *переміщення* (процес) — *видовга*, *обтяг* або > *обтяж*, *переміст* (*наслідок*) <sup>110</sup>.
>
> Відзначена тенденція, цілком виправдана, звичайно, у своїй основі, в разі її «системного» ускладнення, як і в інших подібних випадках послідовної
> «есперантизації» словотвірної системи української мови, ледве чи
> виявиться життєздатною. Крім того, в узусі вже усталилося чимало
> випадків, коли «коротші» форми означають не тільки наслідки дії, а й
> її саму (причому важливо, що вони не пов’язані прямим віднесенням до
> момен- тів завершеності / незавершеності дії), і, як видається, значна
> частина мовного соціуму не хотіла б змінювати цей стан справ,
> наприклад: *вияв* (від відповідного зворотного дієслова — при рідше
> вживаному *виявлення*), опис (при значно рідше вживаних *описування* і
> *описання*), *запис*, *огляд*, *догляд* та ін.; у парі *перетинання* / *перетин*
> (кордону) друге з цих слів уживається все-таки значно частіше.

[Тараненко О. О. Актуалізовані моделі в системі словотворення сучасної української мови (кінець ХХ – ХХІ ст.). – К.: Видавн. дім Д. Бураго, 2015. – 248 с.](http://www.inmo.org.ua/assets/files/Taranenko.%20Aktualizovani%20modeli%20(2015).pdf)

До речі, в українській мові можливе потрійне розмежування:

- **дія — подія (наслідок дії) — наслідок події**.

Наприклад:

- *відновлювання* - дія, *відновлення* - подія, *віднова* - наслідок події.

> **Насамперед це стосується правила виокремчого позначення дії, події (що їх помилково в ДСТУ 3966-2009 названо незавершеним і завершеним
> процесом), а також наслідків події.**
>
> У **ДСТУ 3966-2009** зазначено, що ***українська мова, на відміну від
> російської, має властивість не тільки в дієсловах, а й у віддієслівних
> іменниках розрізняти назви дій (процесів) і подій, а також їх
> наслідків***. Російським дієсловом *изменять* і *изменить* відповідає один
> російський іменник *изменение*, що означає дію, подію і наслідок цієї
> події: (*продолжительность изменения, результат изменения і сравнение изменений*). Українською мовою маємо три іменники: *змінювання*, *змінення*
> та *зміна*. Тому правильне вживання цих іменників у словосполуках:
> *тривалість змінювання, результат змінення* та *порівнювання змін* робить
> ужитковий текст досконалішим й українським. Адже дія *змінювання* – те,
> що відбувалося, відбувається чи відбуватиметься; подія *змінення* – те,
> що сталося чи станеться; результат *зміна* – те, що ми отримали чи
> отримаємо.
>
> Те саме можна сказати про іменники: *оцінювання*, *оцінення* й *оцінка*;
> *передавання*, *передання* й *передача*; *відбивання*, *відбиття* й *відбиток*;
> *деформування*, *здеформування* й *деформація*; *устатковування*, *устаткування*
> й *устатковання*; *розраховування*, *розрахування* й *розрахунок* та багато
> інших.
>
> Коли є паралельні форми дієслів, що означають дію (*розтягувати* та
> *розтягати*, *розроблювати* та *розробляти*), може бути чотири іменники:
> *розтягування* та *розтягання*, *розтягнення* й *розтяг*; *розроблювання* та
> *розробляння*, *розроблення* й *розробка*.
>
> Іменники, що означають дію, утворюють від дієслова недоконаного виду:
>
> - *оцінювати* → *оцінювання*;
> - *подавати* → *подавання*;
> - *устатковувати* → *устатковування*;
> - *розраховувати* → *розраховування*,
>
> а іменники, що означають подію, утворюють від дієслова доконаного виду:
>
> - *оцінити* → *оцінення*;
> - *подати* → *подання*;
> - *устаткувати* → *устаткування*;
> - *розрахувати* → *розрахування*.

[Ребезнюк І. Спробуймо писати та говорити за національними, а не радянськими правилами. Збірник наукових праць учасників XIII Міжнародної наукової конференції «Проблеми української термінології СловоСвіт 2014».](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Zbirnyk_2014/TK_Zbirnyk_2014_3_rebeznuk.htm)

Comment: Я чув про таке, але мені воно раніше здавалося чимось контрнауковим і відірваним від реального слововжитку. (1) Чим все-таки *дія* від *події* відрізняється? (2) деякі з наведених слів відсутні у словниках; (3) виглядає схожим на спробу або натягнути реальну мову на якусь бажану (хоч, можливу, логічну) конструкцію, або на (припустимо) прогноз майбутнього розвитку мови на основі речей, що ще тільки почали викреслюватися. Але можу помилятися.

Comment: @Sasha, я також можу помилятися, але НМД, якраз, виглядає цілком науково. Re(1): подія — наслідок дії, а явище — наслідок події. Re(3): так, можливо, дещо занадто *прескриптивно* (а не *дескриптивно*), але слушно.

Comment: @bytebuster, я не бачу абсолютно ніякого зв'язку з реальним слововжитком — мені воно схоже на конструкції, що існують винятково в голові у певних науковців задля успішного захисту робіт — але можу помилятися.

Comment: Хм... Здається я зрозумів... Щось типу «пошук» («шукати») → «знаходження» («знайти») → «знахідка»; «вдивляння» («дивитися») → «бачення» («бачити») → «вид»? Але тоді я би називав це не «дія, подія (результат дії), результат події», а «спроба дії, успішна дія, результат дії». Крім того, якщо «відновлювання» → «відновлення» → «віднова» в цю схему більш-менш вписується, то от з «оцінюванням» → «оціненням» → «оцінкою» в мене сумніви. (І, припустимо, якщо в мові з'явиться слово «відновля́ння», то куди воно попаде — перша роль же вде зайнята «відновлюванням»?)

Comment: І, у будь-якому випадку, ця відповідь особисто мені набагато більш до вподоби, ніж the accepted one, бо вона мене вчить чомусь, чого я раніше не знав.

Comment: @bytebuster, питання в тому — чи правильному вона вчить (чи просто якомусь більш-менш логічно виглядаючому міфу). Але я недостатньо компетентний, можу помилятися.

Comment: @Sasha, думаю, ключове слово тут — герундій.