# Як бути з віддієслівними іменниками на -ння, -ття?

Tags: вживання-слів, віддієслівні-іменники

Митрополит Іларіон (Іван Огієнко) у праці "Наша літературна мова" пропонує оминати віддієслівні іменники на `-ння`, `-ття` і уживати безсуфіксальні. Наприклад, не *прокляття*, а *прокльон*; не *запитання*, а *запит*; не *змагання*, а *змаг*.

У Панаса Мирного маємо: *Наслухавшись глузу та посміхів* (а не глузування та насміхання).
У Є.Тимченка знаходимо: *обмежа, розум, впад* замість книжних: *обмеження, розуміння, падіння*.

Чи використання таких форм справді є ненормативним?

Comment: А що залишиться від слова "каяття"?

Comment: Чесно кажучи, я не розумію, чим це запитання принципово відрізняється від інших ([один](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3744/), [два](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3106/), [три](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1202/)) на цю ж тему. І відповідь тут така само: усі форми є нормативними; вживаються у залежності від того, в якому контексті слово використовується з-поміж **дія-подія-наслідок**. Або я чогось не зрозумів у <s>запитанні</s> питі.

Comment: @bytebuster, зараз зрозумів, що я неправильно сприйняв зміст запитання на початку. Неуважно прочитав і мені здавалося, що воно зовсім про інше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Борис Антоненко-Давидович у ["Як ми говоримо"](http://yak-my-hovorymo.wikidot.com/viddiyeslivni-imennyky-diyeslivni-slovospoluky) думає так:

> Візьмімо фразу з газети: «Завдання ліквідації будь-яких порушень статутів і настанов, рішучого зміцнення дисципліни вимагають докорінного поліпшення контролю за діяльністю підлеглих, розумного використання дисциплінарних прав, усунення помилок в роботі». Усі слова в цій фразі — українські, а разом із тим звучить вона не по-українському. Чому? Тому що її переобтяжено віддієслівними іменниками: порушення, зміцнення, поліпшення, використання, усунення. Таке нагромадження їх з одноманітними закінченнями порушує мелодійність звучання монотонним «няканням», ускладнює фразу — аж стає важко зрозуміти її зміст.
>
> Українська мова в побудові речення надає переваги дієслову в неозначеній формі й різних особових формах, а також дієприслівнику над віддієслівним іменником. Ідучи за цією вимогою, треба було наведену вище фразу скомпонувати так: «Завдання ліквідувати будь-які порушення статутів і настанов та рішуче зміцнити дисципліну вимагають докорінно поліпшити контроль за діяльністю підлеглих, розумно використовувати дисциплінарні права, переборювати помилки в роботі». З п’ятьох віддієслівних іменників залишився тільки один, конче потрібний, — *порушення*, вся фраза від того полегшала, стала простішою, приступнішою.
>
> **З цього, звісно, не слід робити хибних висновків, ніби віддієслівних іменників треба скрізь уникати. Вони є в українській мові, без них годі обійтись. Вони звичайно виконують у реченнях функцію підмета або додатка: «Заучування слів дисциплінує пам’ять» (О. Ільченко); «Вона наче шукала виправдання для того, чого їй не хотілось робити» (Ю. Смолич).**
>
> Іноді між дієсловом і віддієслівним іменником є деяка значеннєва різниця, наприклад: «Я не люблю заучувати» і «Я не люблю заучування». Друга фраза має далеко ширше поняття, бо в ній мовиться про те, що людині взагалі не подобається, коли щось завчають, тимчасом як у першій фразі йдеться лише про те, що їй самій не подобається заучувати.

Також в [Українському правописі](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par80p4) присутні правила щодо правильного написання віддієслівних іменників на -ння.

І [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/prokljattja) дає тлумачення цих слів.

І стаття [Проблеми вживання віддієслівних іменників в українській мові](https://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2770) дає підтвердження, що в деяких випадках без віддієслівних іменників не обійтись, а також що безсуфіксальні та віддієслівні іменники на -ння,-ття мають дещо різні значення.

**Отже, підсумовуючи все вище сказане, можна зробити висновок, що віддієслівні іменники на -ння, -ття є нормативними, оскільки вони присутні в українських словниках та українському правописі. В деяких випадках їх дійсно можна замінити, але деколи без них не обійтись.**