# "Одиниця вимірювання" чи "одиниця виміру"?

Tags: вживання-слів, віддієслівні-іменники

Я перечитую велику кількість газетних матеріалів. Писала опис і вже не вперше помічаю, що використовують досить часто *"Одиниця виміру"*.

Перечитувала різні джерела, слово наче є але чи можна вживати його саме таким чином?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Роздум

«Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010—…) містить обидва варіанти (але не у статтях [вимір](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9612&page=333) чи [вимірювання](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=9621&page=333), а у визначеннях інших слів):

> [**БІТ**¹](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=171&wordid=152852), а, *ч[оловічий рід]*, *інформ[атика]*. 1. Одиниця вимірювання кількості інформації та об'єму пам'яті комп'ютера. <…>
>   [**КІЛОБА́ЙТ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?page=1319&wordid=183141), а, *ч[оловічий рід]*, *інформ[атика]*. Одиниця вимірювання пам'яті комп'ютера, що дорівнює 1024 (2¹⁰) байтам. <…>
>   [**КІЛОМЕ́ТР**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=41780&page=1318), а, *ч[оловічий рід]*. Одиниця вимірювання довжини, що дорівнює 1000 метрів. <…>
>
> ---
>
> [**ГЕРЦ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=18205&page=632), а, *ч[оловічий рід]*. Одиниця виміру частоти коливань. <…>
>   [**ДЖО́УЛЬ**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=21923&page=749), я, *ч[оловічий рід]*. Одиниця виміру енергії. <…>
>   [**КЮРІ́**](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/?wordid=46471&page=1484), *невідм[інюване]*, *ч[оловічий] і с[ередній рід]*, *фіз[ика]*. Одиниця виміру радіоактивності. <…>

## Вживаність

Наступні джерела містять обидва варіанти приблизно в однаковій кількості (принаймні, кількості відрізняються не на порядки) з деякою перевагою для *вимір*:

- Google Книги — *одиниця вимірювання* [≈137](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D1%83%22&lr=lang_uk&num=10&start=130), *одиниця виміру* [≈123](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D1%83%22&lr=lang_uk&num=10&start=120);
- Google Scholar — *одиниця вимірювання*  [≈1350](//scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F%22), *одиниця виміру* [≈4260](//scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D1%80%D1%83%22);
- Leipzig Coprora — [одиниця](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en/res?word=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F&corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014):

  - сумісність — *вимірювання* ≈2100, *виміру* ≈6240;
  - праворуч — *вимірювання* ≈3100, *виміру* ≈8540.

## Висновок

Здається, обидва терміни є прийнятними.

Див. також: [Як бути з віддієслівними іменниками на **-ння**, **-ття**?](/q/3084)

Answer (score 4):

Наявна відповідь демонструє практичний вжиток, тому я зосереджуся на формальних морфологічних правилах.

Питома морфологія української мови передбачає три споріднені види віддієслівних іменників, що позначають **дію, подію та наслідок**¹.

- *вимірювати, вимірювання* — **Дія** — вплив одного об'єкта на інший (або об'єкта самого на себе), розглядане як явище взагалі;
- *вимірити, вимірення* — **Подія** — те, що відбулося, відбувається чи відбудеться у конкретному місці, часі тощо;
- *вимір* — Наслідок, об'єкт, **стан** та ін.

Тепер розглядаємо їх по одному.

- Подія *вимірення* — це одноразовий феномен, одне конкретне *вимірення*, яке відбулося в деякому місці і в деякий час. Воно у даному випадку нас не цікавить.
- Дія *вимірювання* — тут складніше. В загальному випадку, дія може мати кількісну характеристику: *швидкість переміщення у просторі*. Але *вимірювання* такої характеристики не має. Тобто, формально, *одиниця вимірювання* — це не зовсім правильно, але завдяки вищенаведеній неоднозначності багато хто вважає, що  *вимірювання* має кількісну характеристику, і тому використовують словосполучення *одиниця вимірювання*.
- Наслідок, стан *вимір* — ідеальний кандидат. Ми проводимо *вимірювання*, що призводить до якогось **стану**, який має кількісну характеристику, яка називається ***одиниця виміру***.

#### Висновок

- *Одиниця виміру* — ідеально правильно з точки зору української морфології;
- *Одиниця вимірювання* — не найбільш точне, але дуже поширене.

---

#### Чтиво

¹) [УклАдення чи укладАння договору?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3744/)

Comment: _Дія – це фаза плавного переходу з одного стану в інший протягом скінченного або нескінченно великого проміжку часу, тоді як подія – це «стрибок» з одного стану в інший за нескінченно малий (нехтовно малий) проміжок часу_

Answer (score 0):

Вважаю що термін одиниця виміру застосовується для системи вимірювання СІ (СГС) тобто для стандартизованих одиниць вимірювання (тобто метр, грам, секунда, Джоуль, Ампер, Ватт та інші)
Якщо одиниця не відноситься  до стандартизованої системи СІ (СГС) або є похідною, народною  чи іншою  правильним буде термін одиниця вимірювання ( тобто для одиниць ярд, гектар, баррель, фунт, крок, палець та інші)

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: Ставлю мінус, тому що протягом доби автор не доклав зусиль до покращення відповіді.

Comment: Андрій Лукін, дуже цікава думка. Однак чи є щось, що підтверджувало б таке розділення? Наприклад, підручник, який рекомендує таке слововживання, чи просто якісь матеріали, що де-факто так уживають?