# У чім різниця між «підтримання» і «підтримування»?

Tags: віддієслівні-іменники, означення

> ПІДТРИ́МАННЯ, я. *сер*. Дія за значенням [підтримати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidtrymaty).
>   ПІДТРИ́МУВАННЯ, я, *сер*. Дія за значенням [підтримувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidtrymuvaty).

І далі:

> ПІДТРИ́МАТИ див. підтримувати.
>   ПІДТРИМУВАТИ, ую, уєш, *недок.,* ПІДТРИМАТИ, аю, аєш, *док., перех.*

Виходить, що *підтримування* від недоконаного *підтримувати*, а *підримання* від доконаного *підтримати*.

Але і *підтримання*, і *підтримування* це процеси, тому мені не дуже зрозуміла їхня доконаність/недоконаність.

Comment: Поставив правильний теґ [tag:віддієслівні-іменники], він має кілька інших запитань на тему [дія-подія-наслідок](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3751/8).