# УклАдення чи укладАння договору?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, віддієслівні-іменники, legal-terms

Зустрічала як формулювання "*уклад**е**ння* договору", зокрема, у статті 638 [Цивільного кодексу України](http://zakon5.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/435-15/page11), так і "*уклад**а**ння* договору", зокрема,
[тут](http://stud.com.ua/44422/pravo/ukladannya_dogovoru).

[Академічний тлумачний словник (1970—1980)](http://sum.in.ua/s/ukladannja) містить наступні тотожні визначення:

> УКЛАД**А**ННЯ 1 (ВКЛАДАННЯ), я, сер. Дія за значенням укладати.

та

> УКЛАД**Е**ННЯ 1 (ВКЛАДЕННЯ), я, сер. Дія за значенням укласти.

Все ж спостерігається неоднакове вживання цих слів.

[Тут](http://pidruchniki.com/10391214/marketing/poryadok_ukladannya_dogovoriv) же одночасно є таке:

> Порядок укладання договорів
>
> Етапи укладення договору

*Яка стилістична різниця між словами "уклад**е**ння" та "уклад**а**ння" та чи є вона взагалі? Коли яке з них слід використовувати?*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

*уклад**а́**ння* — це іменник на позначення **дії**, а *укла́д**е**ння* — на позначення **події**.

---

#### Морфологія

Питома морфологія української мови передбачає, що від більшості видових пар¹ дієслів можна сформувати по три віддієслівні іменники, що позначають **дію, подію та наслідок**.

**Віддієслівний іменник на позначення дії** — це, власне, процес виконання цієї дії;
**—//— події** позначає феномен або явище;
**—//— наслідку** позначає кінцевий результат або мету виконання дії.

Для наочності можна скласти таку таблицю²:

| ДІЯ | ПОДІЯ | НАСЛІДОК |
| --- | --- | --- |
| узгоджувати | узгодити | угода, згода |
| узгоджування | узгодження |  |
|  |  |  |
| ухвалювати | ухвалити | ухвала |
| ухвалювання | ухвалення |  |
|  |  |  |
| укладати | укладати | уклад, укладання(?) |
| укладання | укладення |  |

Останній приклад свідчить, що дієслово недоконаного виду *укладати* має однакову форму для дії і події, а віддієслівні іменники є різними (*уклад**а́**ння* проти *укла́д**е**ння*) тому буває важко визначити, яка з цих форм відповідає формі дієслова.

---

#### Практичне вживання

Морфологія віддієслівних іменників — це одна із тем, де серед мовознавців нема консенсусу. Іноді справа доходить до прямого голосування:
«[Протокол № 4](http://tc.terminology.lp.edu.ua/TK_Komisija/Protokol_2002_04.pdf) письмового голосування науково-технічної комісії з питань термінології при Держстандарті України щодо вживання віддієслівних іменників» (PDF).

Документ за попереднім посиланням також містить гарну таблицю, яку варто опублікувати у рамках цієї відповіді:

> Слова, з якими треба сполучати віддієслівні іменники, утворені від інфінітива недоконаного виду, що означають **дію** (те, що відбувалося, відбувається чи має відбуватися):
>
> - **завжди**: *тривалість, засоби, способи, метод, методика, правила, технологія, процедура, функція, порядок, настанови, рекомендації, під час, в процесі*
>
> Слова, з якими треба сполучати віддієслівні іменники, утворені від інфінітива доконаного виду, що означають **подію** (те, що відбулося чи має відбутися):
>
> - **завжди**: *момент, мить, свідоцтво, посвідка, акт*
> - **здебільшого**: *дата, день, місяць, рік, план, звіт*

---

#### Офіційно

Офіційно, правила вживання віддієслівних іменників регулюються документом **ДСТУ 3966:2009**.

Установчі документи, прийняті у різних галузях господарства, також посилаються на ДСТУ 3966, як-то [Про затвердження Рекомендацій щодо вживання термінів та визначень з безпеки руху поїздів](http://uazakon.com/documents/date_1i/pg_imccwj/pg8.htm)

---

¹) Видова пара — це така пара лексично тотожних дієслів доконаного і недоконаного виду, що розрізняються між собою лише граматичною семантикою виду: *робити-зробити*, *переписати-переписувати*.

²) Серед академічної літератури є також думка, що віддієслівні іменники на позначення **події** утворюються від дієслова **доконаного** виду, а іменники **дії** — від дієслів **недоконаного** виду. Наприклад, [«Україномовні терміни з процесуальними значеннями»](http://repo.knmu.edu.ua/bitstream/123456789/5462/1/%D0%A3%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%90%D0%87%D0%9D%D0%9E%D0%9C%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%86%20%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%A0%D0%9C%D0%86%D0%9D%D0%98%20%D0%97%20%D0%9F%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%A6%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%90%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%9C%D0%98.pdf) (PDF, стор. 6). Щоправда, немає спільної думки стосовно того, чи це універсальне правило.