# Як правильно, акт звірки чи звіряння?

Tags: вибір-слова, віддієслівні-іменники, legal-terms

Серед облікових документів є форма акту, в якому погоджуються підсумки взаєморозрахунків. Зазвичай його називають актом *звірки* розрахунків. Але гугл-пошук видає результати акт звірки і акт звіряння. СУМ-11 містить обидва слова з тотожним значенням. Чи є аргументи на користь використання певного з них у бухгалтерському обігу, чи відмінності немає?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Дія-подія-наслідок](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3751/).

СУМ неправильно стверджує, що усі три слова [звірення](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvirennja), [звірення](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvirjannja) та [звірка](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvirka) — «Дія за значенням звірити/звіряти».

Насправді, `-яння` — дія, `-ення` — подія, `-` (без суфіксу) — наслідок. Маю припущення (не перевіряв), що у слові *звірка* суфікс `-ка` зʼявився для уникнення збігу зі словом *звір* (тварина).

Згідно ДСТУ 3966:2009 (див. також [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3749/8)),

> Слова, з якими треба сполучати віддієслівні іменники, утворені від інфінітива доконаного виду, що означають **подію** (те, що відбулося чи має відбутися):
>
> - **завжди**: *момент, мить, **свідоцтво, посвідка, акт***
> - **здебільшого**: *дата, день, місяць, рік, план, звіт*

Отже, *посвідка/акт **звірення***.

Comment: Смішно, оскільки можна (було) легко уникнути, јакшчо б дьіјало правило _ставити **ь** всьуди, де помјакшенньа_, тобто _зьвір_ (тварина).

Comment: @follower, можливо, але чи варто займатися «затиканням дірок» у гонитві за фонетичністю? Етимологічно, *звір* від грецького θηρός і лат. ferus «дикий», споріднене з нім/англ swine. Нема там ані м'якого знаку, алі його попередника, зредукованого голосного `[i]`. Ну, от просто нема. :)

Comment: Ну, така справа не тільки тут, подібне, наприклад, і з _сьвіт_ та _світ_. Тобто мова, јак годитьсьа, підлаштовује під себе, от пан задав анґліјське _свајн_ та німецьке _швајн_ — котрі теж далекі від _ѳероз_ (можливі заміни _ѳ_ — _т^х_, _е_ — _і_) або _ферус_ за звучнеју. До речі, дльа декотрих словјан _сьвіньа_ је такоју собоју нормоју.