# Як перекласти "возврат" як іменник

Tags: переклад, іменники, from-russian, віддієслівні-іменники

Іноді в тогрівельних фірмах можна почути таке:

> Галю, там багато на *возврат*?
>   Що, знов *возврат* привіз?

Тут йдеться про повернення товару. Тобто, наприклад, магазин повертає товар постачальнику. І цей процес і товар, що повертається російською називається *возвратом*.

В аналогічній ситуації *розкладення* переходить в *розклад*. А от для *повернення* таку форму, як результат дії, я утворити не можу. Як це можна сказати українською?

Comment: Шчо міркуıете про [вороття](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/8081-vorittja-2.html)?

Comment: @stegetsj я думав про це, але воно якось по звучанню нагадує дію. І дійсно на [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) багато прикладів в яких вживання схоже саме на дію.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Повернення* — це і є іменник. Віддієслівний іменник. Він має всі ознаки іменника як-то рід (середній) та відмінювання за відмінками: *повернення, поверненню, поверненням* тощо.

СУМ неправильно [класифікує](http://sum.in.ua/s/povernennja) це слово лише як «**дію** за значенням *повернутися*». Насправді, у класифікації «дія-подія-наслідок» це слово може означати як дію, так і наслідок дії.

Напевне, автора збив з пантелику середній рід цього іменника. Наприклад, у московському язику, бідному на морфологію взагалі і суфікси зокрема, <sub>москв.</sub> *возврат* і багато інших віддієслівних іменників виду «наслідок дії» є словами чоловічого роду, утвореними безсуфіксальним способом.
В українській ці слова можуть бути як безсуфіксальні чоловічого роду (*розсуд*, *постріл*), так і середнього роду, утворені за допомогою суфіксів `-ня` (*змагання*), `-тя` (*заняття*, *завзяття*) та інших.

#### Чтиво

- [Як правильно, акт звірки чи звіряння?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4157/8)
- ["Одиниця вимірювання" чи "одиниця виміру"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3106/8)
- [УклАдення чи укладАння договору?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3744/8)

Comment: Як тоді перекладете _возвращение_? Там _ние = ння_. Котра вже дія дія від _возврат_. Ось так пастка.

Comment: @stegetsj Тобто ви хочете сказати що для будь-яких двох мов, два різні слова в одній мові завжди перекладаються двома різними словами в іншій мові?

Comment: @Artemix переважно так, коли мова про Словянські мови. Але пастка в тому, же тут мова була про бідну морфолоґию Московської мови, хоча я навів хибність такого мисленя саме в цӧму випадку. І взагалі, Українцӥ мають велику проблему розмежу таких подібних слів, чого не сказати наприклад про Московську чи Польську, де така розмежа відносно красша. Тобто для умовного Москаля _возрващение_ і _возврат_ легкорозріжні тямки.

Comment: @stegetsj, бідність московського єзика не в тому, що йому бракує чужих (словʼянських) суфіксів. А в тому, що ці суфікси, будучи чужими і неприродніми для московського єзика, **використовуються неконсистентно**. Приклад — москв. *«здание»*, яке походить від москв. *«воЗДвигать»*. Порівняйте *«знание»* від *«знать»*. А суфіксів чужих надьоргати можна звідки завгодно: оно московити запросто поцупили [німецький суфікс `-ieren`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ieren) (*капитулИРовать*, *музицИРовать*), і нічого, їм норм. :)

Comment: @bytebuster, в українській мові використання слова «язик» у значенні «мова» вважається застарілим. Я б змінив «у московському язику» на «у московській мові» (в ідеалі — на «у російській мові», це найнейтральніше, але це вже не наполягаю), бо поточне формулювання (разом з не дуже обґрунтованими прямо в цій відповіді словами про бідність) здається схожим на кепкування і показує нас не дуже добре.

Comment: @Sasha, ви маєте рацію, ми маємо бути чемними. Наприклад, московити масово (0.9 млн хітів) використовують зворот [*«на мове»*](https://www.google.com/search?q="на+мове") `[nʌ mo.vʲe]`, що є транскрипцією. Якщо припустити, що подібне явище є виразом глибокої поваги до нас (а ми не маємо права вважати інакше, чи не так?), то і ми можемо (мусимо?) використовувати симетричний вираз *«на єзикє»*. Чим символізуватимемо неабияку повагу до них, і ні в якому разі не кепкування. Навпроти ж, зворот *«у російській мові»* може ображати братній народ і показуватиме нас не дуже добре.

Comment: @bytebuster, «московити масово (0.9 млн хітів) використовують зворот „на мове“ [nʌ mo.vʲe]» — саме так, і я не хочу їм (точніше, найгіршим із них) у цьому вподібнюватися. («Поваги… неабияку повагу» — можливо, я неправильно це інтерпретую, але, по-моєму, це більше схоже на взаємне кепкування, якому в серйозних осередках не місце. Та навіть на https://rus.stackexchange.com і https://russian.stackexchange.com Ви такого не побачите.)

Comment: @bytebuster Не заперечую, же Московська має проблеми з ростками, особисто про цӧго наголошував в нашіј мові, коли же вони занесли шчось такого до нас. Але я мовив саме про цӧго випадку, де всє відносно гаразд, навіть _здание_ тут не виняток, котре від старого _здать_ (_со-здать_), словопоходом від _зьдъ_ «стїна» (котрого втратили, ось тут вже нелоґика), відки також наприклад _со-зидать_ і _зодчий_, А _воз-двигать_ иншого корня, приростка _воз-_ (_воз-зієднати_) теж маємo, але не про цӧго тут мова.

Answer (score 2):

На розум поки нїчого не приходе крім корня **vьrtĕti*: *верт* і *ворот*, шчо збіжні з сенсом *turn*. Приросток *re-* значе *знов* (маємо *пере-*) або *назад*, для кортого нїчого не маємо чи не пригадую і мусимо знаходити окреме дїӧслово.

Загалом, як на мене, нај-красше пасують *зворот* і *поворот*. Коли брати саме зміст зї запитаня, то за словником СУМ [*зворот*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=35065&page=1114) підходе:

> 7. *рідко.* Повернення назад, до попереднього, колишнього; вороття.
>
>    1. *Минає день, минає два, Мина за ранком ранок .. Перевернувся цілий рік, – Як перш, нема звороту* (П. Грабовський);
>    2. *Нема тобі, Маріє, звороту. Йди до кінця* (У. Самчук)
>
>    Повернення назад чого-небудь узятого, відібраного у когось.
>
>    1. *Він в 1841 році зчинив правдивий розрух у громаді і зажадав від пана звороту всіх загарбаних від того часу ґрунтів* (І. Франко)
>
> **Без зворо́ту**, у знач. присл.
>
> 1. безповоротно, назавжди.
>
>    1. *І він оддав їй своє серце навіки, без звороту* (Б. Грінченко)

До цїкавого, же переклад від Ґуґл радить *поверт*: словники не закрїпюють, але словотворчо можливо, до того ж маємо подібного утвору: *заверт* — котрого СУМ не крїпить, але инші [цїлком](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82&highlight=on).

Answer (score -2):

```
повернення
```

Ця форма дуже часто використовується як в бізнесі, так і побуті.

Comment: Дякую, та для мене воно більше звучить як процес, а не як результат.

Comment: @Yola воно може бути і процесом і результатом