# Укладка (іменник)

Tags: синоніми, іменники, віддієслівні-іменники

Для позначення певних типів зачіски застосовується як іменник "укладання". Шукаю кращий відповідник. Прошу допомоги.

Comment: Позначив це запитання теґом [tag:віддієслівні-іменники]. Інші запитання за цим теґом гарно розкривають тему.

Comment: @bytebuster, тобто Ви теж за те, щоб оте, що на голові в результаті, називати _укладкою_, а сам процес називати _укладанням_ — я правильно розумію?

Comment: @Sasha, я за те, щоб позначити це запитання відповідним теґом. :) Відповіді на запитання я не надавав. Але якщо цікава моя думка, то — *уклад{-ка}*, згідно [(1)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/4159/8) і [(2)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3751/8)

Answer (score 1):

Нічого кращого не спадає на думку, ніж запозичити якийсь іншомовний термін, наприклад:  *фризур* (нім. Frisur).

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: І таке слово [вживається](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac8&queryselector=wordrow&word=фризур.*), і є навіть у словниках ([1](http://sum.in.ua/s/fryzura), [2](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=фризур*&dicts=1&highlight=on)) — щоправда в жіночому роді (_фризу́ра_) й означає зачіску загалом (а не конкретно укладку).