# Як правильно з рос. мови перекласти "таро расклад" ? Розклад - це русизм?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Як правильно з рос. мови перекласти "таро расклад" ? Розклад - це русизм?

Answer (score 1):

**Розклад** може бути наслідком **розкладення**. І [r2u](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) таке слово в такому значенні знає:

> Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–
>
> - *политические расклады* – політичні розкла́ди (пасьянси);

[Зі статті](https://r2u.org.ua/node/108) Виталя Моргунюка у віснику Нац. ун-ту "Львів.політ.", №503, 2004. – С.75–81:

> Згідно з рекомендаціями [6] та вимогами [3, п. 5.1.4; 4, п. Г.4.1], дію треба позначати віддієслівними іменниками на *–**нн**я* (*–**тт**я*), утвореними від дієслів недоконаного виду, подію – віддієслівними іменниками на *–**нн**я* (*–**тт**я*), утвореними від дієслів доконаного виду, а об'єкти (наслідок події) – відповідними однокореневими іменниками з іншими суфіксами або без них, наприклад:
>
> ```
> Дія            | Подія        | Наслідок
> --------------------------------------------
> згинання       | зігнення     | згин
> змінювання     | змінення     | зміна
> нарізування    | нарізання    | нарізь
> повертання     | повернення   | поворот
> розтягування   | розтягнення  | розтяг
> устатковування | устаткування | устатковання
> ```

І приклад:

> Від багатьох видових пар у словниках української мови (наприклад, [14; 18]) зафіксовано три віддієслівні іменники, що позначають дію, подію та наслідок події. Треба правильно вживати ці віддієслівні іменники, розрізняючи їх значення, наприклад:
>
> - Аналоговий сигнал передає інформацію завдяки неперервному **змінюванню** *(дія)* амплітуди або частоти
> - Використанням раціоналізаторської пропозиції визнають створення або **змінення** *(подія)* конструкції виробів, технології виробництва та застосовуваної техніки або складу матеріалу
> - Фазовий зсув – це **зміна** *(наслідок події)* фази сигналу

Додаткове чтиво:

- ["Одиниця вимірювання" чи "одиниця виміру"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3751/9)
- [УклАдення чи укладАння договору?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/3749/9)