# Спробуємо перекласти "halving"?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

Тематика блокчейн зараз дає чимало нових лексем, які потребують фахового погляду під час перекладу. Цікавить слово **halving** на позначення процесу запланованого вкорочення винагороди за завершений блок під час видобутку біткоїна.

> Each time a new block is added to the bitcoin network, freshly minted
>   bitcoins are rewarded to whichever miner discovered the valid block.
>   This reward, initially set to 50 BTC, fell to 25 BTC in late 2012.
>   Sometime next month, this number is expected to fall to 12.5 BTC. This
>   event is known as a "halving".

[coindesk](https://www.coindesk.com/making-sense-bitcoins-halving/)

Російські перекладачі упоралися так, що створили (чи дібрали готове) слово [**уполовинивание**](https://coinspot.io/news/breaking-news/upolovinivanie-bitcoina-prohodit-uzhe-segodnya/).

**Уполовинювання**, калькуючи рос. варіант, ажніяк не елегантно. **Вкорочення вдвічі**?

Словник дає слово [**половинити**](http://sum.in.ua/s/polovynyty), яку форму матиме віддієслівний іменник? Чи є інші думки?

Answer (score 4):

Оскільки саме явище криптовалют нове, словникового слова для них нема, і тому доводиться розглядати загальне явище (зменшення чогось удвічі). Думаю, тут можна навіть обійтися простою логікою, без словників.

*Halving* є процес зменшення удвічі, причому не одноразова подія, а постійно-повторювана **дія**.

Розглядаємо протилежний процес збільшення чогось удвічі, яке має цілком усталену форму ***подвоєння***, утворений з кореня `-дв-` за допомогою префікса `по-` і низки суфіксів.

Тепер просто ставимо потрібний корінь `-половин-` і звертаємо увагу, що префікс `по-` нам не дуже підходить, щоб уникнути повторювання. Замінюємо на схожий за значенням `у-` (`в-`).

Отримаємо **вполовинення**.

Див. також *уповільнення*, *вподобання*.

Comment: Не певен щодо форми, може відповідь на [це питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1202) допоможе.

Answer (score -2):

Згідно до онлайн словника Мультитран слово "halving" перекладається як "деление пополам", тобто "поліл навпіл" або ж "розподіл навпіл". Інші перекладені варіанти з того ж Мультитрану: "зменшення в два рази", "скорочення в два рази", "роздвоювання". Всі слова з російської на українську були перекладені в Гугл Перекладачі.

Сам же Гугл, якщо ввести слово "halving" дає варіант "вдвічі зменшити", тобто якщо вам потрібний іменник, то отримаєте "зменшення вдвічі".

Comment: Під час опису halving використовують слово reduce, яке по суті своїй означає перевести у простіший стан. Зменшення в два рази - не логічне. Кількість збільшується. Розмір зменшується.